# Getting First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty while trying to allow users to edit their password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to add a solution to allow users to change their password. I am using devise. And I followed up the third solution from this [tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password).
However after I do everything:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update_password
    @user = current_user
    if @user.update_with_password(user_params)
      # Sign in the user by passing validation in case their password changed
      bypass_sign_in(@user)
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    # NOTE: Using `strong_parameters` gem
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

in routes.rb

```
resource :user, only: [:edit] do
  collection do
    patch 'update_password'
  end
end
```

and in the view:

```
 <%= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "update_password" } ) do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
    <%= f.password_field :current_password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password, "Password" %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off"  %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <div class="action_container">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

but I get this error `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` in
`= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => 'update_password' } ) do |f|`

is there something I have missed? Thanks!

Comment: Show us the PUT or POST log you're doing

Comment: as I just reload the page I get this error. `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 447ms` , `ArgumentError - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty:
`

Comment: Oh, `@user` can't be nil or empty. So, what happens if you do `p @user` in your controller. What do you see?

Comment: @VeridianDynamics sorry, but what do you mean `p @user`?

Comment: I'm just trying to know what's inside `@user`.It is likely nil. So you need to show me what's inside it to prove that to me. I have a feeling `current_user` is resolving to nil and, thus, `@user` is nil and, thus, the server throws and error when trying to generate the HTML markup for your form. `p @user` placed inside your controller after the assignment of `@user` will just print it to your logs.

Comment: @VeridianDynamics okay, but somehow it doesn't print it bcz I can't find it.

Comment: @VeridianDynamics however I have `@current_user` in instance variables printed

Comment: I'd have to know a lot more about your environment to help solve this. It's clear to me that you don't have a `current_user`. That's why this isn't working. Did you install the Devise gem and hook up your User model to the devise gem? If not, do that first.

Comment: No I have a current_user that I am logged in with, and I did install the devise gem and the user model is hooked up to the devise gem like so: `devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190868/discussion-between-veridian-dynamics-and-ga4696).